# Need help changing msql_results to an equivalent of PDO instead

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo, pagination

I am having an issue trying to figure how to replace mssql_result so that this code can work for mssql not MySQL. I have tried different ways still little lost on what to do. If anyone has any examples on how to do this would be big help. I will continue to try figuring it out and then post answer if I find it.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    $serverName = "localhost";
    $objConnect = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$serverName ; Database=maintenance", "test", "test123") or die("Error Connect to Database");
     $strSQL = $objConnect->prepare("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE status='Received' ORDER BY id DESC");
     $strSQL->execute();

    $Num_Rows = $strSQL->fetchColumn();

    $Per_Page = 2;   // Per Page

    $Page = $_GET["Page"];
    if(!$_GET["Page"])
    {
        $Page=1;
    }

    $Prev_Page = $Page-1;
    $Next_Page = $Page+1;

    $Page_Start = (($Per_Page*$Page)-$Per_Page);
    if($Num_Rows<=$Per_Page)
    {
        $Num_Pages =1;
    }
    else if(($Num_Rows % $Per_Page)==0)
    {
        $Num_Pages =($Num_Rows/$Per_Page) ;
    }
    else
    {
        $Num_Pages =($Num_Rows/$Per_Page)+1;
        $Num_Pages = (int)$Num_Pages;
    }
    $Page_End = $Per_Page * $Page;
    IF ($Page_End > $Num_Rows)
    {
        $Page_End = $Num_Rows;
    }

    ?>
    <table width="600" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th width="91"> <div align="center">Lan ID </div></th>
        <th width="98"> <div align="center">Name </div></th>

      </tr>
    <?php
    for($i=$Page_Start;$i<$Page_End;$i++)
    {
    ?>
      <tr>
        <td><div align="center"><?php echo mssql_result($objQuery,$i,"lanId");?></div></td>
        <td><?php echo mssql_result($objQuery,$i,"name");?></td>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </table>

    <br>
    Total <?php echo $Num_Rows;?> Record : <?php echo $Num_Pages;?> Page :
    <?php
    if($Prev_Page)
    {
        echo " <a href='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$Prev_Page'><< Back</a> ";
    }

    for($i=1; $i<=$Num_Pages; $i++){
        if($i != $Page)
        {
            echo "[ <a href='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$i'>$i</a> ]";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<b> $i </b>";
        }
    }
    if($Page!=$Num_Pages)
    {
        echo " <a href ='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$Next_Page'>Next>></a> ";
    }

    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Where does it fail? Connecting, querying, fetching, other?

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: @chris85 Call to undefined function mssql_result() I get this error and the records do not show up.

Comment: These questions always get downvoted so hopefully if i figure it out it will help others

Comment: You cant use `mssql_*` with PDO, nor in general if running PHP 7. It is probably downvoted because you didn't really define a specific problem which makes more work for us.

Comment: ok I should have reworded it I know msql cannot be used with PDO I need help figuring how to change this to work for pdo

Comment: Do a `fetch` to get the data. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: I do know its fetch but I am little confused were to put it because of the pagination. This code works for mysql so I was trying to convert it to work with mssql

Comment: Swap `for($i=$Page_Start;$i<$Page_End;$i++)` with a `while(fetch...){` then replace `mssql_result($objQuery,$i,"lanId")` with the array (assigned in the fetch) and index you want, if assoc and `$row` it'd be `$row['lanId']`.

Comment: Still having hard time I will keep trying with clue you gave me

Answer (score 0):

```
<table width="600" border="1">
  <tr>
     <th width="91"> <div align="center">ID </div></th>
    <th width="91"> <div align="center">Lan ID </div></th>
    <th width="98"> <div align="center">Name </div></th>

  </tr>
<?php

while($result = $strSQL->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ))
{
?>
  <tr>

    <td><div align="center"><?php echo $result["lanId"];?></div></td>
    <td><?php echo $result["name"];?></td>

<?php
}
?>
</table>
```